# What is URL of Web Farm in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, server, webserver

I made a web farm in IIS and added two local iis websites to that :

[image: iis web farms]

now how can i access my web farm? in other words what is my web farm URL that users will access it?

do i need to redirect requests from one of my IIS websites to web farm?if true,how can i do that?

i have added a rewrite role to send all requests from default website to this url:

http://AnimalFarm/{R:0}

but i get 404 error.

i'm using iis 10 in Windows 10 Enterprise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a third server that will act as a [load balancer - ARR server](http://doc.dynamicweb.com/documentation-9/how-tos/install-setup/load-balancing-with-microsoft-arr-for-iis8). Then you will use the url of your ARR server to access your web farm. Once you install the ARR module in IIS you can define the backend servers and affinity policy:

[image]

So only the ARR server needs to be publicly accessible. The backend nodes hosting your application can be in your private network.